# Need readable pure SQL equivalent of SQL Closures code

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle, closures

Have you heard of **SQL Closures** or any library that implements them ?

They allow to execute this script in SQL command window (or put it into SP):

```
exec closure,"
    rec{select db=name from sys.databases where name like 'corp_'},{
        use |db|
        rec{select tbl=name from sys.tables where name like 'user_'},{
            for{col},{Created,Modified},{
                def_col {
                    |tbl|.|col| datetime not null default(getdate()) ix
                }
            }
            def_col {|tbl|.deleted datetime ix}
        }
    }
"
```

This script will make sure that Created not null, Modified not null and Deleted indexed columns exist in all tables with prefix user_ in all databases with prefix corp_.

`def_col` will create new column or alter existing column to match desired definition. It will also create/recreate non-unique ascending index for each of these columns.

`def_col` will drop and recreate dependencies as needed (constraints, indexes, foreign keys, schema bound views and functions).

`rec` and `for` and `def_col` will catch errors and log them into error table or raise immediately depending on context options for easy debugging and tracking of errors during script execution should they happen.

As you can see, the script can be executed many times without failures, it's just second time it will not change anything.

Is there a more readable, supportable and compact way to achieve the same functionality in MS-SQL ?

If yes - please post example in your answer.

Is more readable, supportable and compact way available in MySql, Oracle or other major flavors of SQL language ?

Comment: Where have you heard of this term from? Personally, I would never recommend doing functionality in Dev, Test, and Prod in the same time.. there's a reason for deployment timelines.

Comment: I invented it. Ok, I agree, that was just imperfect example that came to my head. I fixed it.

Comment: Good deal, but I still wouldn't recommend working on n-databases in parallel. How would you handle errors that would arise? Or what would happen if your data becomes corrupt in one database and not in another? I don't see the simplicity in that at all. If you want something readable, work with a database one at a time, and audit what you do.

Comment: I see, I need to provide better example, because it does not stand well against valid critique. I will work on it.

Comment: Better example is ready for critique.

Comment: No available library implements what you describe.  Some tools help execute multiple statements but none of them use a pure database solution.  Using a GUI or a non-relational technology kills most of the benefit.  It's a shame because what you describe is incredibly useful.  I know because I've built an Oracle PL/SQL API very similar to this.  It was difficult to build and use, I'm not surprised nobody else has built one.  If I can ever convince my company to open source it, I'll post it here.

Comment: Thank you Jon. I posted my quick implementation here: https://gutlib.svn.beanstalkapp.com/g/sql/do.sql You will find other interesting things in my GutLib library.

Comment: Latest implementation is available here: http://sql-do.alpav.com

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any reason you could not create simple `SQL` Server Groups in `SSMS,` and register your servers against those groups and run your `DDL` from there. You could also do it with `SQLCMD`, or `Powershell.`